# Flutter Alphabet only keyboard without textfield

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and trying building a spelling learning app where user will get some hints and based on that user will guess the word.
So basically, I need to take keyboard input from user for each letter and if the letter is in the spelling, it will print that letter and if not it will simply ignore.
I am struggling to get a keyboard with only alphanumeric keys and responds with every key press events.
Is there a package available for this activity.

- I tried with 'VirtualKeyboard' but it has numbers and special
  characters which I don't want.
- I also tried with 'builtinkeyboard'
  which needs a textfield which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z]")),
        ],
        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
),
```

use default TextFormField and validate with RegExp then whenever user tries special character it will be ignored